# No "redefinition of default parameter error" for class template member function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, templates, compiler-construction

Why does the following give no compilation error?:

```
// T.h

template<class T> class X
{
public:
    void foo(int a = 42);
};
```

---

```
// Main.cpp

#include "T.h"
#include <iostream>

template<class T> void X<T>::foo(int a = 13)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    X<int> x;
    x.foo();   // prints 42
}
```

It seems as though the **13** is just silently ignored by the compiler.  Why is this?
The cooky thing is that if the class template definition is in *Main.cpp* instead of a header file, I do indeed get the *default parameter redefinition* error.

Now I know the compiler will complain about this if it were just an ordinary (non-template) function.

What does the standard have to say about default parameters in class template member functions or function templates?

Comment: g++ *does* abort compilation with an error.

Comment: When you say "...if the template declaration is in..." I'm assuming you mean the class template definition i.e. `template<class T> class x{....};`. If so then you're saying that replacing the include directive with this template class definition produces a different compiler message? That suggests that there is something else in the header file i.e. try copying the entire contents of the header file into where the include directive was and presumably then you get no compiler warning?

Comment: It could be related somehow to this VC++ bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/496593/msdn-forum-splitting-templated-function-with-default-argument-into-declaration-definition-gives-compilation-error

Comment: @STingRaySC: It certainly is bizarre. Can't see how the issue in @Kirill's link relates at all to it though. At the end of the day the preprocessed output must be different if you're getting different compiler errors i.e. it's the preprocessor that's key here. Try spitting out just the preprocessed code in each case. You'll be able to spot some difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **8.3.6 §6** The  default  arguments  in  a member function definition that
> appears   outside of the class
> definition are added to the set of
> default  arguments provided by the
> member function declaration in the
> class definition.
> [Example:
>
> ```
> class C {
>     void f(int i = 3);
>     void g(int i, int j = 99);
> };
> void C::f(int i = 3) // error: default argument already
> { }                  // specified in class scope
> void C::g(int i = 88, int j) // in this translation unit,
> { }                          // C::g can be called with no argument
> ```
>
> --end example]

According to the standard, it should give you an error.

Comment: @tusbar you are quoting only part of that paragraph. It says at the start of it "Except for member functions of class templates, ...".

Comment: Interesting: C++03 differs from C++98. What @tusbar quoted is the C++98 text, while C++03 added the exception for class templates and added to the paragraph "Default arguments for a member function of a class template shall be specified on the initial declaration of the member function within the class template." - i suspect that this is meant to forbid default arguments in out-of-class definitions in case of members of class templates by saying that any default arguments shall be specified in-class [instead of outside of the class] however to me it seems unclear (does it forbid duplicates?).

Comment: I looked into http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#217 and it seems like the intention is to forbid any out-of-class default arugments for template members. Also, i think now since the out-of-class default argument is regarded distinct from the one in-class, even if lexically identical, it violates the "shall be specified on the initial declaration" constraint. So this makes sense if you get a compile time error. The "issue 3.13" John Spicer refers to can be read in this document: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0607.pdf